# css - Put scrollable table on remaining height (between header and footer)

Tags: css

[Attached Img.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSUXl.png)
Please refer to attached image. I have a `Header`, `content` and `Footer`.

Both `Header` and `Footer` are fixed. They should be visible at all times.
And inside the `content`, I have a `<table>`. I want to make this `<table>` take all the remaining height between the `header` and `footer`.

The table might contain a lot of data, so I want to make it scrollable as well.

The snippet below shows the closest I got by putting the `table` into a `div` with `overflow-y: auto; max-height: 200px;` (fixed size)

How can I make it take the full / remaining height automatically?

```css
body {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  background: lime;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Some awesome title
</div>
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Lorem.</th>
        <th>Numquam.</th>
        <th>Id.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Eos.</td>
        <td>Vel.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Quod.</td>
        <td>Quaerat?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Explicabo!</td>
        <td>Esse.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Quo.</td>
        <td>Praesentium!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Perferendis!</td>
        <td>Necessitatibus.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Facere.</td>
        <td>Ex.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Ducimus.</td>
        <td>Architecto.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Porro!</td>
        <td>Voluptatum.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Culpa?</td>
        <td>Dignissimos?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Alias.</td>
        <td>Deserunt!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Mollitia!</td>
        <td>Doloribus?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Quia.</td>
        <td>Aspernatur.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Est!</td>
        <td>Nihil.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Neque.</td>
        <td>Asperiores!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Cupiditate.</td>
        <td>Rerum.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Eligendi.</td>
        <td>Qui?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Libero.</td>
        <td>Molestiae!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Suscipit.</td>
        <td>Nostrum.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Minima.</td>
        <td>Voluptatem.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Quam.</td>
        <td>Mollitia.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Minus!</td>
        <td>Corporis.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Perferendis.</td>
        <td>Deleniti.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Asperiores!</td>
        <td>Rem.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Molestiae.</td>
        <td>Dignissimos?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Doloribus.</td>
        <td>Ipsam.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Aperiam.</td>
        <td>Obcaecati.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Suscipit.</td>
        <td>Harum?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Cupiditate.</td>
        <td>Tenetur.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Ea!</td>
        <td>Ipsam.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Officia!</td>
        <td>Velit.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Mollitia!</td>
        <td>Voluptatibus.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Rerum.</td>
        <td>Accusamus?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Distinctio.</td>
        <td>Ducimus.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Iure.</td>
        <td>Recusandae.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Quibusdam.</td>
        <td>Veritatis.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Optio!</td>
        <td>Voluptatum.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>At.</td>
        <td>Facere.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Illum?</td>
        <td>Placeat!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Unde?</td>
        <td>Explicabo.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Reiciendis.</td>
        <td>Architecto.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Quasi?</td>
        <td>Praesentium!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Odit!</td>
        <td>Ratione.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Expedita?</td>
        <td>Incidunt!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Nemo.</td>
        <td>Reprehenderit?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Blanditiis.</td>
        <td>A.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Iusto.</td>
        <td>Similique.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Sint?</td>
        <td>Corrupti.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Consequatur.</td>
        <td>Nihil!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Magni.</td>
        <td>Deleniti.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem.</td>
        <td>Nobis!</td>
        <td>Eius.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Pagination stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this HTML:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">table</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

You were searching for this CSS solution (as flexbox is not supported in IE9):

```
body {margin: 0;}
.header {height: 50px;}
.content {height: calc(100vh - 100px); overflow-y: scroll;}
.footer {height: 50px;}
```

But I would use/prefer this one:

```
body {margin: 0;}
.header {height: 50px; position: fixed; top: 0;}
.content {padding: 50px 0;}
.footer {height: 50px; position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
```

The latter one uses the normal page scroll, instead of a div overflow, which causes less cross browser issues and better performance on (older) mobiles.

Comment: Thank you, I can see why the latter one would be preferred. I'd definitely do it like that for cases I mentioned in the question.

As I failed to provide and also predict that I would be adding additional controls (like sub-header/sub-footer. Eg.: select item > make set of controls for `edit`/`delete`), flexbox works well for scenarios like this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find screen display height using jQuery and use it to set height of table. Scrolling will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with flexbox following this snippet: https://codepen.io/anthonyLukes/pen/DLBeE

Previous attempts on using it failed, because I also had a "Navbar" which I thought didn't matter, as it was all wrapped inside a `<router-outlet>` like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <div class="main">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I tried using flexbox, my footer wasn't visible.. the content area was "taking all remaining areas".. that's what I thought..

So what I did to fix was:
1. put a `margin-top` with the height of the navbar on the `.header`

```
.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
}
```

2. make the div that's wrapping the header, content, and footer "move up":

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

There's probably a better and correct way of doing this, I don't have a good understanding of how flexbox works.. yet, but what I noticed, is that `flex: 1 1 auto;` will "grow/expand to the remaining height", the height of the entire page, not the height of its parent's div.

So adding a `margint-top: 2.5em;` to the header, is basically forcing it to take into account the "navbar's height" when calculating how much it can grow.

Once that's done, I shift the entire thing up again by the same margin.

Here's the end result: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwTQM.png)

Comment: if there's a better/correct way of doing this, let me know, and I'll change the correct answer. Thank you